# Single ESC closes ALL modal dialogs in jQuery UI. Workarounds?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, dialog, keyboard-shortcuts, modal-dialog

Actually, there was (is still) a bug in jQuery: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4511.

The reason for this behavior (from the bug description comments): "The dialog itself binds keydown event to itself for closing the dialog on <kbd>ESC</kbd>; in addition, the dialog overlay binds a keydown event to the document, without filtering to close only the active dialog."

I cannot come up with an idea of an acceptable workaround. Is there anyone who has had to deal with it yet?

Comment: Don't show multiple *modal* dialogs simultaneously. That's bad UI, and probably the reason this bug (actually a duplicate of this one: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3539) hasn't been touched in 2 years.

Comment: I cannot think of a better solution in my case. It is quite standard. I have a jqGrid that on click in certain cells opens a history of the object (10-200 lines in most cases) with a header offering some actions. Each history message has "view details". It is quite natural to stack two modal dialogs on top of each other in this situation. But I am open to suggestions... Also, actions on the first dialog can prompt warnings (e.g. Delete asks for confirmation)

Comment: Tried with non-modal dialogs. Here, 'Esc' closes only the last opened dialog (even if it is in a background). Pressing Esc again has no resul. But it might be a way to go, with some changes (keep only one dialog of the same type open, process Esc 'manually'). Will try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple - upon creating a modal dialog, run this:

```
$([document, window]).unbind('.dialog-overlay');
```

If you create more then one modal dialog, hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> will close the top one only.
Then once you focus on the bottom dialog, hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> and it will close it as well.

Hope this helped!

P.S. jQuery UI developers should add an option when you want all dialogs close at once upon hitting <kbd>ESC</kbd> key or only the focused ones.

Comment: Thanks for getting back at that one! This answer is not a complete solution, but fixes the problem. However, it also prevents from ESC-ping lower dialog after tompost was ESC-ped. But it did put me on the right track. What I did as a workaround I will post as a separate answer.

Comment: "prevents from ESC-ping lower dialog after tompost was ESC-ped" - that is true, of course, only until you click at least once on the bottom dialog (Jazzer said as much in the answer). So, for someone looking for a simpler solution, this one liner could work really well.

Comment: Is this applicable for hitting Enter too? I have popups opening one on top of another. If I use this code, will hitting Enter key will submit only the top pop-up or all?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing is I have added `event.stopPropagation();` in close function before `return self;` in jquery.ui.dialog.js file. And I am done with problem of closing dialog boxes one by one on escape keydown.    Let me know if anyone find any better solution.

EDITED:
this need to add because while clicking on close button event object is undefined.

> if(typeof event != 'undefined'){
>       event.stopPropagation(); }

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is that jQuery UI keydown event propagates through all dialogs. A fix in the original jQueryUI Dialog code would be to add `event.stopPropagation()` when topmost dialog was successfully closed and check `event.isPropagationStopped()` at the beginning of the same keydown event.

As a workaround I did, thanks for Jazzer, the following.

1. Set dialog option `closeOnEscape` to `false`
2. When dialog gets created, append:

   `//newDialog is dialog's content, e.g. var newDialog = $('my dialog content>');
   newDialog.keydown(function(event) {
        if (mydialogs.hasOpenDialogs() && 
            event.keyCode && 
            event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE) {
                           $(newDialog).dialog("close");
                           event.preventDefault();

                           event.stopPropagation();
       }
   });`
3. when document is loaded do:
   `$(function(){
   //allow for ESC to close only top dialog
   $(document).bind('keydown', function(event) {
       if (event.isPropagationStopped()) return true;
       if (mydialogs.hasOpenDialogs() && 
           event.keyCode && 
           event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE) {
                           mydialogs.closeTopDialog();
                           event.preventDefault();
                           event.stopPropagation();
       }
   });
   });`

Event in (2) happens when user hits <kbd>ESC</kbd> while typing text in input box inside of the dialog.
Event in (3) happens when user hits <kbd>ESC</kbd> somewhere else.

`mydialogs` here is a wrapper around stack (array) of modal dialogs, where every new dialog adds itself via `.push()` and in `.close()` removes itself with `.pop()`.