# How do I prevent ESC in editable-options propagating to the jQuery-ui dialog it's in?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using the [editable-options](http://code.google.com/p/editable-options/) plug-in for a SELECT element on a jQuery-UI dialog. Editable-options allows for a select box in which users can, as the name suggests, edit the OPTION elements.

The editable-options documentation says, "The user may cancel the changes by pressing escape."

The problem is that the ESC keypress event is either propagated up to or detected independently by the dialog that the select control is in, and not only does it cancel the changes made to the particular item that the user is editing, but any other changes they may have made in the dialog. *Not* a happy user experience.

I did some research (mostly reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744070/single-esc-closes-all-modal-dialogs-in-jquery-ui-workarounds) and the links it led to), and figured I should put a call to e.stopPropagation() into the escape-key event handling in the editable-options code, but that didn't work.

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1 and jquery-ui 1.8.16 (which is supposed to have the fix for the problem described in the link above, but of course that's only in the dialogs themselves, not editable-options).

Can someone point me in the right direction, please? Or tell me if it's just not possible to fix, though if that's the case, it kind of makes editable-options unusable. I'll continue my own researches and if I find something, I'll either add it here or answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out and, as promised, here's the answer.

It turns out that the editable-options code handles the *keyup* event, while the jQuery UI dialog code handles the *keydown* event, which, of course, occurs earlier. So the editable-options code can't intercept the event.

I added a keydown handler in editable-options, in which I called e.stopPropagation() and presto! Problem solved.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get in touch with the developer so I can suggest the change?